# javascript: How to convert a array of string into a pure string that concatenate the items separated by comma?

Tags: javascript

I have an javascript array of string that looks like:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I want to convert it to (all string):

```
strA = '"a","b","c"'
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: do you mean `'a, b , c'` -> `strA = A.join(', ')` - [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: No. I meant literally `\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"`, I am just looking for a simple solution

Comment: Or `'"' + A.join('", "') + '"';`

Comment: @tushar very beautiful answer

Comment: @Tushar not required... you can post that... was suppose to add that.. then saw you have already posted it as a comment

Comment: `JSON.stringify(A).slice(1,-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `join` with `","` as glue.

```
var strA = '"' + A.join('","') + '"';
```

`join` will only add the *glue* between the array elements. So, you've to add the quotes to start and end of it.

Comment: Minor adjustment: `var strA = '"' + A.join('","') + '"';`

Comment: @davejagoda Removed space from glue

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
A.toString();
alert(A);
```

Comment: No quotes around `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try just concatenating the values in a simple for loop
something like this:

```
var array = ["1", "a", 'b'];
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
  str += '"' + array[i] + '",';
}
str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
```

or if you're feeling crazy you could do :

```
   str = JSON.stringify(array)
   str = str.substring(1, str.length -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? This works in chrome.

```
function transformArray(ar) {
  var s = ar.map(function (i) { 
    return "\"" + i + "\","; })
  .reduce(function(acc, i) { 
    return acc + i; 
  });
  return s.substring(0, s.length-1);
}

transformArray(["a", "b", "c"]);
```